# Which is default value --tags in ansible-playbook run?

Tags: ansible

Which is the default value `--tags` in ansible-playbook run?
How can I fix a empty value for `--tags` because I have error for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default value for tags is `all`.

Comment: Thanks Konstantin Suvorov.